# SQL Server Select top 10-20 results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns the first one I want top 10 products (1-10)

That is

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Product
```

In the second column I want the next 10 results (11-20)

How do I do that?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: What platform MySql or SQLServer?

Comment: @Nicklas Visit these threads : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364292/sql-server-2005-select-top-n-plus-other

Comment: In SQL Server 2011 (codenamed "denali") you'll be able to do `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Something OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` which is quite awesome :)

Comment: @AlexBagnolini Can you put that as the answer as it really is the more correct one now? - and without it being an answer people might miss it in the comments.

Comment: @monty - it might be helpful to people who come across this from search results but it is not an answer to the question here. The question here is about putting rows 1-10 into the first column and rows 11-20 in the second column. Not something `OFFSET ... FETCH` helps with

Comment: @MartinSmith True, rereading the questions 5 years later I can see that :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT TOP 20 name, 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RN
FROM Products
ORDER BY id
)
SELECT 
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN <=10 THEN name END) AS Col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN > 10 THEN name END) AS Col2
FROM T       
GROUP BY RN % 10
```

Comment: I must admit how much I enjoy reading Martin's and Marc's solution's. +1 for both

Comment: +1 darn - this is even a lot smarter and less "taxing" on the execution plan than my solution - congrats!

Comment: @marc_s this is what I mean I enjoy reading. Different approaches & solutions make me (at least) think in a better way :)

Comment: @niktrs: indeed - I enjoy seeing other (very smart!) guy's solutions, too - helps me get better at my stuff every day! :-) (and Martin here is one of the top SQL gurus around for sure - saved my bacon a couple of times already :-) Thanks Martin!)

Comment: Thanks for the ego boosting comments!

Answer (score 14):

I would do this:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table names] ORDER BY [column name] DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

This is simpler and less complex....

What do you guys think?

Comment: It does not seem to work on SQL Server, but if you replace LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 WITH OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
Then it'll work on SQL Server.

Answer (score 9):

```
select top 10 wwwhid from wwwh  where wwwhid not in(select top 10 wwwhid from wwwh)
```

Comment: Clever and sharp

Comment: @KhurramShaikh Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Starting with SQL server 2012 [order by offset/fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms188385(v=sql.110)) feature:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY someIdField 
    OFFSET 10 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, it's bit tricky to get this done. If you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer, you can use a CTE with a `CROSS JOIN` and some trickery to get the result you're looking for:

```
;WITH TopProducts AS
(
    SELECT 
        ProductID, ProductName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY --some-column-here-- DESC) 'RN'
    FROM dbo.Products
)
SELECT 
    p1.ProductID, p1.ProductName,
    p2.ProductID, p2.ProductName
FROM 
    TopProducts p1
CROSS JOIN 
    TopProducts p2
WHERE 
    p1.RN BETWEEN 1 AND 10        -- get rows 1-10 from the first CTE
    -- AND p2.RN BETWEEN 11 AND 20   redundant, as niktrs pointed out
    AND p1.RN + 10 = p2.RN        -- join rows from P1 and P2 so you don't get a cartesian product
```

The CTE (Common Table Expression) numbers the products - this needs to be based on some column from your `Products` table, but you didn't mention what column defines the order.

We then select rows 1-10 from the CTE, as well as rows 11-20 from a second instance of the CTE. If you leave this as is, you'll get 100 rows - each combination of rows 1-10 from the first result set against each of the 10 rows from the second result set.

That's why you need an additional condition, based on the row numbers, to "join" one row from each result set, and thus you'll get ten rows - the first column has the items 1-10 from the Products table, the second column has rows 11-20

Comment: Althought I thought this would perform better than my code, in my test enviroment makes two index scan's instead of Index seek?! Also I think AND p2.RN BETWEEN 11 AND 20 is redudant because of AND p1.RN + 10 = p2.RN

Comment: @niktrs: you're right about the redundancy - one can even write this as an INNER JOIN and put that `p1.RN = p2.RN - 10` as the JOIN condition - works too

Comment: @marc_s: Logically this *is* an inner join, I think. Anyway, +1, it does its job right.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is the best way to do it but it works

```
select *
from
(
SELECT top 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY product) linenum, product
FROM products
) t1
 JOIN 
(
SELECT top 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY product) linenum, product
FROM products
) t2 ON t1.linenum+10 = t2.linenum
```

Comment: I think this will result in the first 10 rows displayed twice, in both columns, once alone and once together with the other 10. Maybe you meant `INNER JOIN` instead of `FULL JOIN`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @FromRange int
declare @ToRange int
set @FromRange =11
set @ToRange =20
SELECT top(@ToRange-@FromRange+1) * FROM [tbl] 
where tbl_id not in (select top (@FromRange-1) tbl_id from tbl)
ORDER BY tbl_id
```

Comment: The best answer for me too. Thanks a lot

Comment: select top (@FromRange-1) tbl_id from tbl *ORDER BY tbl_id* required for  second query too

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColName) RowNo, ColName
    FROM TableName 
) table1 
INNER JOIN  
( 
    SELECT TOP 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColName) RowNo, ColName 
    FROM TableName 
) table2 ON table1.RowNo + 10 = table2.RowNo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH result_set AS 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (ORDER BY Product.ID DESC) AS 
     [row_number], Product.intId AS id, Product.Title As Title
     FROM Product WHERE Product.Price > 11)
SELECT * FROM result_set WHERE [row_number] BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code:

```
select top 20 * from [table Name] 
except
select top 10 * from [table Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Product LIMIT(10,10)
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `LIMIT`

Comment: No version or edition of SQL Server support `LIMIT` - that's a MySQL custom speciality - not any kind of standard at all

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM 
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY /*some column*/) AS row_num
 FROM Product
) AS p
WHERE p.row_num BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (select *
      from <table>
      order by id asc)
where rownum <= 20

minus
select *
from (select *
      from <table>
      order by id asc)
where rownum <= 10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Feel free to take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName) AS MyRowNumber, *
  FROM TableName) tbl
WHERE MyRowNumber BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform that by using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

This will select rows from my table, it will give me 10 rows, and will skip the first 10 rows.

Comment: This is MySQL, but the OP asked for SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

This my be the most specific:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS MyRowNumber, * FROM table) tbl
WHERE MyRowNumber BETWEEN 11 AND 20;
```